# Where do I find the official "Sign in with Facebook button"?

Tags: facebook

I am looking for the official "Sign in with Facebook" Button but I cannot find it on their website.
E.g. Spotify uses it

> https://www.spotify.com/de/
>   -> "Anmelden"
>   -> "Mit Facebook anmelden"

I found this one here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/

but its not the one I am looking for.
That one is pretty lame to be honest.

Does anyone have an idea where I can find it - or is the one Spotify e.g. uses not even official?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Build your own Facebook-Login-Button and use the following code for login functionality:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-scope="email" onclick="fbStatus();">Connect</div>

<script>
    function fbInit() {
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: 'XXXXX',
                status: false,
                cookie: true,
                xfbml: true
            });

            //auth.statusChange
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
                if (response.status.indexOf('connected') != -1) {
                    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
                    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
                    // request, and the time the access token 
                    // and signed request each expire
                    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                    //Handle the access token

                    });

                } else if (response.status.indexOf('not_authorized') != -1) {
                    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
                    // but has not authenticated your app
                } else {
                    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
                }
            });
        };
    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    } (document));
}

function fbStatus() {

    //auth.statusChange
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
        if (response.status.indexOf('connected') != -1) {
            // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
            // app, and response.authResponse supplies
            // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
            // request, and the time the access token 
            // and signed request each expire
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

            //Handle the access token

            });

        } else if (response.status.indexOf('not_authorized') != -1) {
            // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
            // but has not authenticated your app
        } else {
            // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
        }
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
            // app, and response.authResponse supplies
            // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
            // request, and the time the access token 
            // and signed request each expire
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

           //Handle the access token

            });
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
            // but has not authenticated your app
        } else {
            // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting it right, you require facebook authentication with facebook login

Please refer this link [developer.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web)

Here, you will get everything you want,

1) Here you will find multiple options to achieve what you require

Note: now Iframe option is deprecated, so one must use [JavaScriptSDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript)

Here is the link to create [Login Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button)

and you are ready to go..

sample codes are available in the above link(Sample provided below)..

Step 1: Script Code in beginning of Body Tag.

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.2';
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Step 2: Place this code where you want this plugin to appear

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false">
</div>
```

Note: User can customize UI up-to some extent Refer "Plugin Configurator" in the above link.

I am sure any technical person will be able to achieve using that!

Comment: I have created an app and also implemented the standard button but I thought there is some way to customize it - I have seen that Button in my example a lot and thought that there might be an official version of it but I might be wrong.

Comment: Please provide your code for more detailed solution, a fiddle will do best.. :) if its button's size specific then please be more specific for requirement.

Comment: I created it via https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/

Thats not the problem. The problem is the layout of the button. It looks not how I want it to look. But I guess that IS the official one and there is no possibility to change it.

Answer (score -2):

The official place for facebook logo's and buttons is:

https://www.facebookbrand.com/

Comment: This doesn't contain the "Sign in with Facebook" button.